# 4G access point for incoming VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

My home network Internet access is built on OPNSense providing access over fiber channels. Recently, I've added a 4G access point build on OpenWRT running on a Raspberry Pi, which is part of a gateway group. I case of fiber network failure, the switch over is done by OPNSense. Works pretty good so far. I'm thinking about securing the access to my home network (incoming VPN connection) in case of wired network failure. I've imagined using the 4G access point enabling a VPN connection to an externally hosted server instance (any VPS cloud-hosted could do the job) in case of failure. This would let me access my network in case my backup link is active. Now the question is, how to do that?

Do you guys think it would be possible to establish a VPN connection using Wireguard, to the externally hosted server instance, log on to this instance, and be able to access my LAN? Not sure this would work because the Wireguard Client would be located in my home environment, whereas the server-side would be located at the VPS for instance...

Please let me know your thoughts, just thinking about how I could manage that...

Comment: I have to pay my ISP a small up charge to enable VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sounds like an ordinary "site-to-site" VPN setup. In general, server vs client makes little difference – once the link is established, packets can go through it in either direction by default.

(Though it slightly helps that WireGuard is more of a "VPN building block" – a *tunnel* – than a full 'client' VPN product, so it's fully symmetric both in terms of the underlying protocol that doesn't distinguish "clients" from "servers" at all, and in terms of configuration that doesn't impose any predefined roles. As another example, IPsec/IKEv2 uses the terms "initiator" and "responder" to avoid the unnecessary implications.

But it *would* still be possible to do the same with e.g. OpenVPN in by using 'iroute', just not as pretty; if I had to use OpenVPN for a site-to-site tunnel I'd use the 'tap' mode which is more flexible in nature, while the default 'tun' mode is strongly client-oriented.)

Note: If the home WireGuard endpoint isn't located *on* the main gateway (e.g. if you decide to configure it on the OpenWRT device and not on OpnSense), then don't forget to configure the main OpnSense gateway to have a *route* towards the VPN subnet via OpenWRT, otherwise your LAN devices won't know how to send packets back to the VPS. This isn't anything VPN-specific though.